# How do I get a range of cells with an Excel VBA function to calculate individually and not all display the same value?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I've written a function in VBA that looks at the contents of certain nearby cells and then returns a string based on their values. I want this function to run on a whole column of cells. However, when I fill down, every single cell displays the same value, that of whichever cell I edited and pressed enter for. I've tried setting `Application.Volatile` as well as recalculating the sheet (both using `F9` and `ActiveSheet.Calculate`) but none of those have worked. I also tried setting `ActiveCell.Value` to be the string I want returned, and then not returning anything from the function, but excel says this is a circular reference. Any suggestions?

Here's (the relevant parts of) my code:

```
Function foginSpeechP()
Application.Volatile True
ActiveSheet.Calculate

'.....

If scenario = "SR-1A" Then
    first = "nofog"
    secnd = "fog"
ElseIf scenario = "SR-1B" Then
    first = "fog"
    secnd = "nofog"
Else: foginSpeechP = "NOT A REAL SCENARIO in foginSpeechP"
End If

If (IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)) And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) > 0) Then
    currTimeStamp = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
Else: foginSpeechP = "NO TIME STAMP IN FOGINSPEECHP()"
End If


If currTimeStamp < speechFogChange Then
    foginSpeechP = first
    'ActiveCell.Value = first
Else: foginSpeechP = secnd
    'ActiveCell.Value = secnd
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're referencing the active cell, which is probably the cell selected by the cursor at the moment the function evaluates.

The way to do this is to accept your cell offsets as arguments to your function:

```
Function foginSpeechP(A)

    If scenario = "SR-1A" Then
        first = "nofog"
        secnd = "fog"
    ElseIf scenario = "SR-1B" Then
        first = "fog"
        secnd = "nofog"
    Else: foginSpeechP = "NOT A REAL SCENARIO in foginSpeechP"
    End If

    If (IsNumeric(A) And A > 0) Then
        currTimeStamp = A
    Else: foginSpeechP = "NO TIME STAMP IN FOGINSPEECHP()"
    End If


    If currTimeStamp < speechFogChange Then
        foginSpeechP = first
        'ActiveCell.Value = first
    Else: foginSpeechP = secnd
        'ActiveCell.Value = secnd
    End If

End Function
```

Then, assuming you're calling from A1, call your function from your worksheet like this:

```
=foginSpeechP(E1)
```

Basically, any values from cells that your function uses to calculate it's return value, should be passed in as arguments to the function. See the following for more details:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: This is a better approach than my suggestion - if you pass all inputs as parameters then you don't have to use `Application.Volatile`

Comment: Yeah, I presume you're aware of this yourself Tim, but for the OP: if you use Application.Volatile then whenever a change is made to your sheet anywhere, your function is called. If instead you use cells as arguments to your function, whenever you make a change to one of those cells, your function will recalculate- much more efficient, especially if you have a large number of function calls.

Comment: Perfect! This works. What's the problem with referencing the active cell, though to make the function not re-calculate? Is it that it thinks the active cell is the same for all of the copied-down functions?

Comment: Yeah, the active cell is the selected one at the time the function is evaluated- so every time you click a cell it becomes the active cell. So when you copy down the function, the active cell when the function evaluates is most likely the one you're copying down from. If you were to click on one of your copied down functions and press F9 (to calculate) it would probably display the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Application.Caller` to get the cell the formula is entered in, not `Activecell`

Answer (score 0):

You may not call `ActiveSheet.Calculate` from a worksheet function, and using `ActiveCell` is meaningless.

You probably want to replace `ActiveCell` with [`Application.Caller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193687.aspx).

Better yet, pass the relevant range as a parameter to the function.